# Equations of motion for electromagnetic field coupled with axion-like particle in curved spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, variational-calculus

I've been reading the article "Geometric optics in the presence of axion-like particles in curved space-time" by Dominik J. Schwarz, Jishnu Goswami and Aritra Basu. They introduce the action
$$S=\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \mathcal{L}$$ where the Lagrangian is the electromagnetic field coupled with axion-like particles in curved spacetime:
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu a \partial^\mu a +\frac{1}{4} \textrm{g}_{a\gamma}a F_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}. $$ Here $a$ is the axionic field, $\textrm{g}_{a\gamma}$ is the coupling constant, $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the Maxwell tensor and $\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}=\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}/2$ is its dual tensor. They say that varying the action with respect to the gauge field $A_\alpha$ produces the equation of motion:
$$\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\alpha}-\textrm{g}_{a\gamma}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\alpha}\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial_\rho a=0.$$

I have 2 questions:

1. So far, I have only varied actions w.r.t. scalar fields and not vector fields. How does one derive the Euler-Lagrange equations by varying the action w.r.t. $A_\alpha$ ?
2. I used this form of the Euler-Lagrange equations $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\alpha}=\nabla_\mu \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\nabla_\mu A_\alpha)}. $$ I was only able to derive the first term in the equation of motion. I am familiar that writing the Maxwell tensor in terms of covariant or partial derivatives is the same due to the Christoffel symbols cancelling out. However for the second term I did various index gymnastics but I could not figure out how to produce it. So, how is the second term derived?

Comment: Just a comment, the field strength tensor is defined with partial derivatives. If we were working with torsion where the indices of the Christoffels do not commute, the field strength tensor would not change. You derive the equations as you did with scalar fields. You vary with respect to the field create total drivatives, cancel the total divergence term as a contribution of the boundary and obtain equations of motion.

Comment: @ApolloRa My understanding was the connection is torsion-free, so the Christoffels commute in the lower indices, as it wasn't noted otherwise in the paper. Why won't the field strength tensor change if the lower indices did not commute, the Christoffels won't cancel out in that case? Also, thank you for the instructions. I saw one of your previous answers where you perform exactly that, quite useful.

Comment: Check page 174 of the document http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/newlecturesGR.pdf, i wouldn't explain it better!